# What is the expected startup experience for a Progressive Web Application?

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Testing a Progressive Web Application.

When I start the app in airplane mode, I get an unexpected startup/splash experience (Android/Chrome).

**Launch from Home Screen Experience**

I see a white screen, followed by a brief flash of the "offline dinosaur" before the app successfully starts and all is well. The startup time is longer than I expected, especially after testing with Chrome Devtools on a laptop, where startup is near instant.

Since it is a little tricky to debug where this time is being spent (especially in the “service-worker-not-running” case), it would be helpful to have some baseline knowledge:

**Launch from Browser Experience**

Just a brief flash of the "offline dinosaur" before the app successfully starts. Starts much faster.

**Questions**

- What is the expected startup time and experience on Android/Chrome?
- Is the experience described above just the current state of things (11/2015)?
- Is there any way to specify the startup (splash) experience for Chrome? (I'm aware of background color and 144x144 icon in app manifest for splash, but for Opera only)

First time PWA for me, so any information on this would be helpful.

My platform:
Samsung GS 5,
Android 5.0,
Chrome 46.0.2490.76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the offline-dino flash:

I was using **sw-toolbox** and performing asynchronous work to setup route handlers at worker startup. This caused an offline dino flash when the application was offline and starting up.

To avoid that, set a sw-toolbox default handler that waits for the asynchronous route handler setup to complete.

```js
var toolbox = require('sw-toolbox');

var setupPromise = someAsyncHandlerSetup()
.then(function () {
  // make default handler temporary, allows other fetch handlers (like sw-precache, for example)
  toolbox.router.default = null;
});

// until the async handler setup is done, provide a default handler
// to avoid an offline-dino flash when starting up while offline. 
toolbox.router.default = function defaultHandler (request) {
  return setupPromise.then(function () {
    var handler = toolbox.router.match(request);
    if (handler) {
      return handler(request);
    }
    throw new Error('default handler could not handle ' + request.url);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the existence of the splash screen is because on mobile it can take over a second to start the render process so we paint something (the background colour and icons) util you have a first paint generated by your app.

If you are seeing a white screen on startup it might be because you added to the homescreen prior to Chrome landing (46) the splash screen feature.  Some things to lookout for:

- Ensure your manifest has a `short_name` and `name`
- Ensure your start_url is in the same scope as a SW that is registered on the page
- Have good icons in the manifest ideally > 192px
- Set `background_color` in the manifest to the color of your background on the page (ideally.)  This will ensure that the splash screen is the expected colour of your site.

You shouldn't see the offline dinosaur at all, even when you are in aeroplane mode.  [Airhorner](https://airhorner.com) should represent the ideal experience: Blue splash screen with an icon that morphs into the display of the app.

re: Icons - I recommend actually 192px icon or higher.

Comment: The background_color removed the white screen, however, I still get a brief "dino flash" in airplane mode. Note I have a fetch in my startup sequence (as a result of a network first strategy). I'm going to remove this, but wonder if this causes the dino flash.

Comment: Can you share the URL with me paulkinan @ google if it's private. Your network first approach might be causing it, but even then your SW should handle the request and you shouldn't see the dino

Comment: Sure, paulkinlan. I've since changed to a "fastest" strategy. Start times are faster, but still see a wee flash of dino. Again, only see this when starting from homescreen.

Comment: Upvoted this answer for bgcolor, icon, and render process startup time. Temporarily withholding "accepted" for "flash of dino" explanation. I understand its likely something my sw/app startup is doing, but explanation of that behavior is very valuable. Code is public, here: https://github.com/localnerve/flux-react-example-sw

Comment: Idea for dino cause: The app reads all dynamic routes, including the start route, from IDB and installs fetch handlers. This is an async operation, just started from the service worker startup script - Not on a lifecycle event with a "waitUntil". I did this because I need to setup anytime the service worker starts, not just on install or activate. Maybe that's the cause of the dino? Am I misunderstanding activate?

Comment: I've had more time to debug this, and now I see this is indeed the problem. Accepting this answer as is and addressing the "dino flash" separately in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34009861/is-there-a-service-worker-startup-waituntil-to-delay-processing-fetch