# Is there a Service Worker startup waitUntil to delay processing fetch?

Tags: asynchronous, indexeddb, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to get service workers to wait to begin processing fetch events until asynchronous work completes at service worker startup?

I have an app shell with routes defined in data. To install specific route fetch handlers at service worker startup, I need to lookup route data from IndexedDB (asynchronous).

Unfortunately, the service worker starts accepting fetch events before the IndexedDB lookup can complete and setup fetch handling for routes.

For now, I'm just hardcoding a special case default handler for this, but it would be great to get the service worker to just delay processing fetch events until the IndexedDB processing is complete at service worker startup.

I didn't see a way to "waitUntil" for this, maybe I missed it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a workaround:

```js
function startupAsyncStuff() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    // put here your async stuff and fulfill the promise when done.
  });
}

// Launch your startup async code
var asyncStuffDone = startupAsyncStuff();

// On fetch, wait for the former promise to be resolved first
self.onfetch = function (event) {
  event.respondWith(asyncStuffDone.then(function () {
    // your fetch handling code
  }));
};
```

Comment: This is a good, general case demonstration of the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, this promise driven code is still new to me.  How do you "fulfill the promise when done"?  And what is the "reject" parameter for.  Thanks for your patience with my noob question (:

Comment: @LupusOssorum When calling `new Promise`, you pass a function to it for its first parameter that we will call `f`. Then function f is called with parameters: accept (1st) and reject (2nd). Then function f can call the first parameter passed to it with the resulting value of the expression when it is done with whatever asynchonous thing it is doing, or function f can call reject to indicate that something went wrong.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found, but the downside is that it forces me to call `respondWith()` for every fetch event - when in my case I don't want to make that decision until I've finished my initial asynchronous processing. I really need a way to reliably perform my asynchronous processing _before_ calling (or not calling) `respondWith()`.

Answer (score 6):

A code snippet would help as I'm not 100% clear on the issue... But making a few guesses:

Until you resolve the promise provided to event.waitUntil when you listened for the install event, the SW shouldn't intercept any network requests, so doing the IDB set up there should be fine.

In general it's also fine just to have the fetch event listener run and not do anything, as the browser will fall back to the network as normal in that case.

In general it's also worth beading in mind that SWs can and do get killed frequently so local variables won't stick around between receiving different events. If there's some data you will need when handling a different event, you should keep it in IDB or the Cache API and fetch it from there again.

Comment: Where is the Event.waitUntil for startup? My situation occurs after the SW has been killed and re-starts to service the page.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming the issue was for waiting after installing, not every time it starts up. If the issue is that you need to do an IDB lookup after starting up but before routing the fetches you've intercepted you should be able to call e.waitUntil in the fetch listener and pass back a promise which resolves after you've generated the response, part of which will involve an IDB lookup. Let me know if I'm still misunderstanding, happy to take a look at a code snippet :)

Comment: You've got it now - that's the crux. Looks like the solution IS to add a fetch handler for this and waitUntil. I don't have a "snippet" for this, but the brave/curious can see the [code](https://github.com/localnerve/flux-react-example-sw/tree/master/assets/scripts/sw). Two problems with this **1.** An "offline dino" flash at startup when the sw process is not already running, [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906701/what-is-the-expected-startup-experience-for-a-progressive-web-application) **2.** Delay under lie-fi as needlessly uncaught fetch goes through to network.

Comment: A cache first strategy could solve 2), but incurs the risk of needlessly running the page with an older version of the site. 1) sounds like a bug - you shouldn't be seeing a flash of dino... Does that happen simply when you refresh the page or some other time? If you can repro then we'd really appreciate a description of the issue or video filed on crbug.com so we can get it fixed!

Comment: Happens when I start the app from homescreen or in browser when both of these are true **1.** Offline in airplane mode **2.** Service worker process not running prior to start. It is always happens when these conditions are true, reproducible everytime. I can send you a public url to the staged app. I'll checkout crbug.com.  After testing waitUntil for fetch locally, it doesn't seem to fix it like I thought - might be a bug.

Comment: I don't understand how #1 can happen; as we're waiting for the SW to start up, the page will simply look like it's trying to connect to the network. The key here is to make sure that your `waitUntil(<promise>)` correctly captures the full chain of operations you're waiting on. Code for the fetch handler?

Comment: The code for the actual fetch handlers are in sw-precache and sw-toolbox. These aren't causing the issue. More interesting is the fetch handlers in sw-toolbox are being setup after reading from idb. I tried installing yet another fetch handler that executes sync in the main script that handles just the calls for those routes installed async (and calls waitUntil for the idb resolution). Felt super hacky to do that - I really don't want that solution. I should be able to read idb and install route handlers for sw-toolbox at SW startup time without hacks, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using **sw-toolbox** and performing asynchronous work on startup that setup route handlers, the best solution for me was to define a temporary sw-toolbox default handler until the handlers were ready to respond.

```js
var toolbox = require('sw-toolbox');

var setupPromise = someAsyncHandlerSetup()
.then(function () {
  // make default handler temporary, allows other fetch handlers.
  toolbox.router.default = null;
});

// until the async handler setup is done, provide a default handler
// to avoid an offline-dino flash when starting up while offline. 
toolbox.router.default = function defaultHandler (request) {
  return setupPromise.then(function () {
    var handler = toolbox.router.match(request);
    if (handler) {
      return handler(request);
    }
    throw new Error('default handler could not handle ' + request.url);
  });
};
```